# How to capture interaction between jquery Dialog and Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a call in the parent HTML which invokes a javascript call.

```
<div class="data">
  <form:input title="Building" styleClass="content contractorDisable" maxlength="5" size="6" path="fireImpairForm.bldCode" />&nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:winOpen('LookupLocation.htm','bld')">
    <img src="image/search.gif" border="0" alt="Click here to find Building"></a>
</div>
```

The javascript used for the modal window previously was using a window.showModal where the code has been commented as shown in the javascript code below.
I am looking to have a replacement for this same call through Jquery and using the jQuery dialog code. 
and this is the javascript call that is called which encapsulates a jquery dialog popup. Previously I was able to set a value in the parent input text value to whatever was selected in the modalDialog window using the return object of modalwindow.That code is now commented out to show what it was and what the implementation I am looking for in its place. I am looking for some replacement for that implementation using jQuery dialog. My Dailog is encapsulating another jsp which is a table so I am not able to return the value back to the parent form.

```
function winOpen(urlVal, type) {
  var printNames = new Object();
  var ind = [document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.statusId"].selectedIndex].value;
  ind = document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.facility"].selectedIndex;
  var facilityCode = document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.facility"].item(ind).value;
  var sub = facilityCode.substring(((facilityCode).indexOf("-")) + 1, (facilityCode).length);
  var params = "?bldCode=" + document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value + "&floorCode=" + document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.floorCode"].value + "&campusCode=" + sub + "&check=" + "check" + "&facilityCode=" + facilityCode;

  /*
          retObj = window.showModalDialog(urlVal+params,"","scroll:no;status:no;dialogWidth:620px;dialogHeight:600px;unadorned:yes;resizable=yes");
          if (retObj != null) {
            document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value=retObj.code;
          }
          */
}
var page = urlVal + params;

var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
  .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 625,
    width: 500,
    title: "Buildings"
  });

$dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

The LookupLocation.htm spring controller returns a jsp

```
<BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bottommargin=0 rightmargin=0>
  <center>
    <form name="locForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="code" />
      <DIV style="overflow:auto;clear:both; width:100%; height:525px; border :1px solid;">
        <TABLE onkeydown="if (event.keyCode=='13') return returnToParent()" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="resultTable" width="100%">
          <TBODY>
            <c:if test="${empty resultList}">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="buttonface"><b>No data found</b></td>
              </tr>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${!empty resultList}">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="label">Search:</td>
                <td class="content">
                  <input name="searchFld" type="text" size=15 onChange="">
                </td>
                <td class="content">
                  <input type="button" value="Find" onclick="findString(document.locForm.searchFld.value)">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td nowrap class="searchTableHeader" align="center" STYLE="color:white">Select</td>
                <td nowrap class="searchTableHeader" align="center" STYLE="color:white">Location Code</td>
                <td nowrap class="searchTableHeader" align="center" STYLE="color:white">Description</td>
              </tr>
              <c:set var="evenCount" value="${0}" />
              <c:forEach var="result" varStatus="i" items="${resultList}">
                <c:set var="evenCount" value="${evenCount+1}" />
                <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${evenCount % 2 == 0}">
                    <tr id='row${evenCount}' class="even_row">
                  </c:when>
                  <c:otherwise>
                    <tr id='row${evenCount}' class="odd_row">
                  </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(${evenCount}); setLookupValuesOne("${result.code}");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">
                  <c:out value="${result.code}" />
                </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">
                  <c:out value="${result.description}" />
                </td>
                </tr>
              </c:forEach>

            </c:if>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
      </DIV>
    </form>
  </center>
</BODY>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. 
I have looked at several implementation of jQuery Dialogs and I am not able to piece together how I can have parent form interaction between the jQuery Dialog.
**UPDATED :adding the rendered HTML requested by Mark**

Here is the updated rendered HTML.
Normal behaviour was , when radio button is selected, the window closed and returned the selected object which was set to a input value on the parent form but now the return object is not getting captured and I can not set the input value  fireImpairForm.bldCode

```
 <html>
  <BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bottommargin=0 rightmargin=0>
    <center>
      <form name="locForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="code" />
        <DIV style="overflow:auto;clear:both; width:100%; height:525px; border :1px solid;">
          <TABLE onkeydown="if (event.keyCode=='13') return returnToParent()" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="resultTable" width="100%">
            <TBODY>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="label">Search:</td>
                <td class="content">
                  <input name="searchFld" type="text" size=15 onChange="">
                </td>
                <td class="content">
                  <input type="button" value="Find" onclick="findString(document.locForm.searchFld.value)">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td nowrap class="searchTableHeader" align="center" STYLE="color:white">Select</td>
                <td nowrap class="searchTableHeader" align="center" STYLE="color:white">Location Code</td>
                <td nowrap class="searchTableHeader" align="center" STYLE="color:white">Description</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row1' class="odd_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(1); setLookupValuesOne("PC    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">PC </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">10150 Place</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row2' class="even_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(2); setLookupValuesOne("ON    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">ON </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">1019 Building</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row3' class="odd_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(3); setLookupValuesOne("OG    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">OG </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">19137 Building</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row4' class="even_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(4); setLookupValuesOne("TO    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">TO </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">2011 Building</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row5' class="odd_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(5); setLookupValuesOne("TT    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">TT </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">30133 4 nw Street Building</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row6' class="even_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(6); setLookupValuesOne("TH    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">TH </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">13939 Warehouse</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row7' class="odd_row">
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="content">
                  <input type="radio" name="radioValue" onclick='highlight(7); setLookupValuesOne("N2    ");returnToParent();'>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" nowrap class="content">N2 </td>
                <td nowrap class="content">40th Avenue Warehouse</td>
              </tr>
            </TBODY>
          </TABLE>
        </DIV>
      </form>
    </center>
  </BODY>
</html>
```

Here the jscript calls if that helps.

I am having a time trying to format the three jscript calls . If you need it I will paste it somehow. They are not really important though for what I am asking. The first is highlighting grey and white background depending on selected row number odd or even. The next ones I have added

```
function returnToParent() {
  //var defer=$.Deferred();
  if (document.forms[0].code.value == null || document.forms[0].code.value == "") {
    alert("Please select a row.");
    return false;
  }
  var rowObj = new Object();
  rowObj.code = document.forms[0].code.value;
  if (window.showModalDialog) {
    self.returnValue = rowObj;
  } else {
    //opener.setData(rowObj);
  }

  //defer.resolve("true");//this text 'true' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
  //$(window.opener.document).forms['dialogForm'].dailogFormVal.val=document.forms[0].code.value;
  //$(window.opener.document).find().val(document.forms[0].code.value);
  var parent = $(window.frameElement).parent();
  parent.find("#dailogFormVal").val(document.forms[0].code.value);
  $(this).dialog("close");
}

function setLookupValuesOne(codeValue) {
  document.forms[0].code.value = codeValue;
  var parent = $(window.frameElement).parent();
  parent.find("#dailogFormVal").val(document.forms[0].code.value);
  //$(window.parent.document.getElementById("dailogFormVal")).val(document.forms[0].code.value);
  //$(window.opener.document).forms['dialogForm'].getElementById['dailogFormVal'].value=codeValue;
```

The finally ending "}" is not getting added to the jscript code.

**Updated to show the modified jScript**

```
console.clear();$dialog.append("<iframe id='dialogframe' style='border: 0px; width: 100%;height:100% '/>");$dialog.dialog({autoOpen: false,  modal: true,width: "auto",  height: "auto",  title: "Buildings",  buttons: [{
text: "Close",    click: function() {      $(this).dialog('close');    }  }]});function winOpenDlg(urlVal, type) {    var printNames = new Object();    var ind =[document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.statusId"].selectedIndex].value;   ind = document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.facility"].selectedIndex;  var facilityCode = document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.facility"].item(ind).value;   var sub = facilityCode.substring(((facilityCode).indexOf("-"))+1,(facilityCode).length);    if (type == 'floor') {         if (document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value.length <= 0) {            alert('Please select a building.');    }else {        var params="?bldCode="+document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value+"&campusCode="+sub+"&facilityCode="+facilityCode;
  }
} else if (type == 'room') {
      if (document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value.length <= 0) {
            alert('Please select a building.');
      }else if (document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.floorCode"].value.length <= 0) {
            alert('Please select a floor.');
      }else {
          var params="?bldCode="+document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value+"&floorCode="+document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.floorCode"].value+"&campusCode="+sub+"&check="+"check"+"&facilityCode="+facilityCode;
      }
} else {
      var params="?campusCode="+sub+"&facilityCode="+facilityCode;
}var page = urlVal + params;  $('#dialogframe').attr('src', page);// yours would do this  // here I create a sample set of text to inject  //var sample = '<div id="findem">Hi I am found</div>';var dialogBody = $("#dialogframe").contents().find("body");//$($dialog.find('#dialogframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body);//$('#dialogframe').attr('src', page);// yours would do this // I do this for simplicity and demonstration//dialogBody.html("<div id='original'>First Text </div>");  //dialogBody.append(sample);// add a click event to the dialog contents, you would do different things  dialogBody.on('click', '[id^=row]', function() {    console.log("triggered !!");
console.log(this.id + ":" + this.innerHTML); // id of element clicked document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"]=document.forms[0].elements[this.id].value;});  $dialog.dialog('open');}
```

**Updated to show latest Javascript**

I updated my code and removed any reference to my src location but even then the same error comes up.

```
EditFireImpair.htm?permitIk=301 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined
```

Defined below is the java script code I inserted almost unchanged from what you posted. The dialog does not open up as it does on your fiddle page.

```
    <script>
console.clear();

var $dialog = $('#mydialog');
$dialog.append("<iframe id='dialogframe' style='border: 0px; width: 100%;height:100% '/>");;
$dialog.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: "auto",
  height: "auto",
  title: "Buildings",
  buttons: [{
    text: "Close Me",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }]
});

function winOpenNewDlg(urlVal, type) {
      var printNames = new Object();
    var ind =[document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.statusId"].selectedIndex].value;
    ind = document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.facility"].selectedIndex;
    var facilityCode = document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.facility"].item(ind).value;
    var sub = facilityCode.substring(((facilityCode).indexOf("-"))+1,(facilityCode).length);
    if (type == 'floor') {
       if (document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value.length <= 0) {
            alert('Please select a building.');
       }else {
          var params="?bldCode="+document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value+"&campusCode="+sub+"&facilityCode="+facilityCode;
      }
    } else if (type == 'room') {
          if (document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value.length <= 0) {
                alert('Please select a building.');
          }else if (document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.floorCode"].value.length <= 0) {
                alert('Please select a floor.');
          }else {
              var params="?bldCode="+document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"].value+"&floorCode="+document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.floorCode"].value+"&campusCode="+sub+"&check="+"check"+"&facilityCode="+facilityCode;
          }
    } else {
          var params="?campusCode="+sub+"&facilityCode="+facilityCode;
    }
  var page = urlVal + params;
  //$('#dialogframe').attr('src', page);// yours would do this
  // here I create a sample set of text to inject
  var sample = '<div id="findem">Hi I am found</div>';

  var dialogBody = $($dialog.find('#dialogframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body);
  // $('#dialogframe').attr('src', page);// yours would do this
  // I do this for simplicity and demonstration
  dialogBody.html("<div id='original'>First Text </div>");
  dialogBody.append(sample);

  // add a click event to the dialog contents, you would do different things

  dialogBody.on('click', '*', function() {
    console.log("triggered !!");
    console.log(this.id + ":" + this.innerHTML); // id of element clicked
    document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"]=document.forms[0].elements[this.id].value;

  });

  $dialog.dialog('open');
}


</script>
```

and this is the HTML

```
 <div style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
  <div id="mydialog">
  <input type="hidden" id="bldCode" />
  </div>
</div>

  <a href="javascript:winOpenNewDlg('LookupLocation.htm','bld')">                                                       
                            <img src="image/search.gif" border="0"
                            alt="Click here to find Building"></a>
```

Comment: `var page = urlVal+params;` Note that `params` is declared inside another function and thus is out of scope  and urlVal is undefined- read up on closures.

Comment: Sorry I deleted some commented out code and had an extra "{". I have editted the code and removed the extra "{"

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your rendered html?

Comment: added the rendered HTML. I have removed the jscript calls for simplicity . they are not doing much now. Thanks

Comment: Clearly you need to understand that you are dealing with the iframe document AND the page document and that `document.forms[0].elements["fireImpairForm.bldCode"] = document.forms[0].elements[this.id].value;` will ONLY access one of those depending upon which document that code resides within.

Answer (score 0):

Ok rather than dig into your details let us start with a very simplified example with some comments: See and play with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/kkwpb5b7/

**EDIT:** Note how I put a click event in my code on the dialog content.  This is similar to your 'click something/event of something etc) that you wish to do.

I put a simple svg icon in, yours is a gif (so we have something to click).

Markup (for my examples, yours differs a bit)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <form:input title="Building" styleClass="content contractorDisable" maxlength="5" size="6" path="fireImpairForm.bldCode" />&nbsp;
  <a class='lookuplocation' data-url="LookupLocation.htm" ,data-type="bld">
    <img border="0" alt="Click here to find Building">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
  <div id="mydialog">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now see my "hidden" dialog wrapper? let's use that rather than some in-line script and then inject some content into that (you would use the src)

```
var $dialog ={};
$(document).ready(function()(
    $dialog = $('#mydialog');
    $dialog.append("<iframe id='dialogframe' style='border: 0px; width: 100%;height:100% '/>");;
    $dialog.dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      title: "Buildings",
      buttons: [{
        text: "Close Me",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }]
    });
});

function winOpen(urlVal, type) {
  var params = '?bldCode=howdy'; // put your stuff in here
  var page = urlVal + params;
  //  $('#dialogframe').attr('src', page);// yours would do this
  // here I create a sample set of text to inject
  var sample = '<div id="findem">Hi I am found</div>';

  var dialogBody = $($dialog.find('#dialogframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body);
  //  $('#dialogframe').attr('src', page);// yours would do this
  // I do this for simplicity and demonstration
  dialogBody.html("<div id='original'>First Text </div>");
  dialogBody.append(sample);

  // add a click event to the dialog contents, you would do different things
  dialogBody.on('click', '*', function() {
    console.log("triggered !!");
    console.log(this.id + ":" + this.innerHTML); // id of element clicked
  });
  $dialog.dialog('open');
}
// took this out of the markup because I don't like them there.
$('.data').on('click', 'a.lookuplocation', function() {
  winOpen($(this).data('url'), $(this).data('type'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your code. I played with this and I need help in the dialog.on(click .. implementation. In my case I have a rendered HTML which has radio buttons. id s would be row1, row2 row3 and so and the second <td> would contain the value if you paste the HTML I have  you can see what it looks like.. At the same time , I need to close it on selection.

Comment: I get this exception when running with my embedded src .EditFireImpair.htm?permitIk=301 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefinedwinOpenDlg @ EditFireImpair.htm?permitIk=301(anonymous function) @ VM6234:1. I get error at this line ..   var dialogBody = $($dialog.find('#dialogframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body);

Comment: Basically this says the `'#dialogframe')[0]` was not defined.  Did you use the same markup for the frame with that `dialogframe` as the id?

Comment: This is where I define it `$dialog.append("<iframe id='dialogframe' ...`

Comment: I added the updated Jscript but I was not able to get the format correct and needed to constantly delete the extra spaces which eventually has created  a weird formatted and incorrectly commented out java script. I could not find any way to paste the correctly formatted Jscript but I tried to clean it up to at least be able to post it since it is code.

Comment: I am not using HTML 5 so I could not use the same in HTML markup . The javascript I had to modify a little but I did not change the dialog frame code

Comment: I make the assumption you reference the data attributes.  Here is the html4 link, I have used that in older browsers such as IE6 without issues. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html

Comment: I managed to add all the javascript and HTML I used. I hardly modified your code that you posted and did not insert the src yet but still I get same error. Do you see anything amiss in the code. Thanks

Comment: Create a fiddle with the actual code and markup you are using, difficult to tell without the entire thing; for instance your `$dialog` is undefined if used as it is. IF it helps, I can create a post with fully modified HTML for the client without a lot of the "extra baggage" that is in it currently.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say was that `document.forms[0].elements` was undefined for me since I do not see where all this `fireImpairForm` stuff is in the markup, looks like it MIGHT be something specific to your jsp stuff somehow however that is non-standard HTML and I am not a jsp expert here.

Comment: actual that input text value is what I want my selected radio button to populate for me. fireImpairForm. It fails even before I make that call though.You can ignore it.

Comment: Here is the fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/ttk1eaLj/1/  . I pasted it into my local as HTML and javascript and the failure is same.Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefinedwinOpenDlg. Also my fiddle has a input text defined which is what needs to be populated by the click dailog call